# Mongo aggregation vs Java for loop and performance

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I have a below mongo document stored

```
{
 "Field1": "ABC",
 "Field2": [
    { "Field3": "ABC1","Field4": [ {"id": "123" }, { "id" : "234" }, { "id":"345" }] }, 
    { "Field3": "ABC2","Field4": [ {"id": "123" }, { "id" : "234" }, { "id":"345" }] }, 
    { "Field3": "ABC3","Field4": [{ "id":"345" }] },  
    ]
}
```

from the above, I want to fetch the subdocuments which is having id "123"

ie.

```
{ 
    "Field3" : "ABC1",
    "Field4" : [ { "id": "123"} ]
} ,
{
    "Field3" : "ABC2",
    "Field4" : [ { "id": "123"} ]
}
```

```
1. Java way  
    A. use Mongo find method to get the ABC document from Mongo DB
    B. for Loop to Iterate the Field2 Json Array
    C. Again for Loop to Iterate over Field4 Json Array
    D. Inside the nested for loop I've if condition to Match id value to "123"
    E. Store the Matching subdocument into List 

2. Mongo Way
   A. Use Aggregation query to get the desired output from DB.No Loops and conditions in the Java side. 
   B. Aggregation Query below stages
    I)  $Match - match the ABC document
    II) $unwind - Field2
    III) $unwind - Field4
    IV) $match - Match the with id ( value is "123")
    V) $group - group the document  based on Field3 (based on "ABC1" or "ABC2") 
    VI) execute aggregation and return results
```

Both are working good and returning proper results.
Question is which one is the better to follow and why ? I used the aggregation in restful service get method, So executing aggregation queries 1000 or more times in parallel will cause any performance problems?

Comment: IMO:Unless we analyze your dataset&DB we can't suggest on one over the other, there could be multiple reasons an aggregate could go slow,Proper indexes, a small dataset & proper querying(using `$match`, `$limit` or `$skip` as early as possible)could help you to yield results faster,Most likely for these king of question I would say OP has to dig in thru their code to determine what's best, try check `executionStats` via `db.collection.explain('executionStats').aggregate([])`.Some prefer less logic on DB to ease on its performance, otherway is to say if DB can handle well get less data from DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Aggregation, the whole query is executed as a single process on the MongoDB server - the application program will get the results cursor from the server.

With Java program also you are getting a cursor from the database server as input to the processing in the application. The response cursor from the server is going to be larger set of data and will use more network bandwidth. And then there is processing in the application program, and this adds more steps to complete the query.

I think the aggregation option is a better choice - as all the processing (the initial match and filtering the array) happens on the database server as a single process.

Also, note the aggregation query steps you had posted can be done in an efficient way. Instead of multiple stages (2, 3, 4 and 5) you can do those operations in a *two stages* - use a `$project` with `$map` on the outer array and then `$filter` on the inner array *and then* `$filter` the outer array.

The aggregation:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          Field2: { 
              $map: {
                   input: "$Field2",
                      as: "fld2",
                      in: {
                           Field3: "$$fld2.Field3",
                           Field4: { 
                               $filter: {
                                   input: "$$fld2.Field4",
                                      as: "fld4",
                                    cond: {  $eq: [ "$$fld4.id", "123" ] }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                 } 
          }
      }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          Field2: { 
              $filter: {
                   input: "$Field2",
                      as: "f2",
                    cond: {  $gt: [ { $size: "$$f2.Field4" }, 0 ] }
              }
          }
      }
  },
] )
```

Comment: ,. I tried with $project, $map and $filter but unsuccessful.. could you please give me the sample query for the above Json.

Comment: You can try the answer from this SO post (it has a similar array within array structure and filtering the inner array): [MongoDB- Fetching exact array element, excluding others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492131/mongodb-fetching-exact-array-element-excluding-others).

Comment: I am posting the query. Actually it will have two stages instead of  four stages (I had mentioned one stage in the answer).

Comment: Hi Prasad_, Thanks for the help. Answer works as expected in mongo db but I stuck in implementing the same in spring data. posted new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534705/spring-mongo-aggregation-filter-with-and-in-and-eq-conditions. problem comes when we have $filter.cond with multiple conditions. Unlike criteria, ArrayOperators.Filter / ComparisonOperators.Filter are not providing chaining.

Answer (score 1):

The second way is probably better because it returns a smaller result from the datastore; shlepping bits over the wire is expensive.